# Why can my two threads coordinate through non-volatile fields?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

According to [this specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3), two java threads can not coordinate through non-volatile fields. Why is my code running okay?

```
public class TestVolatileExample {

static int pairCount = 1000;
static VolatileExample[] exps = new VolatileExample[pairCount];
static{
    for(int i = 0;i<pairCount;i++){
        exps[i] = new VolatileExample();
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException{
    final int valuePair[][] = new int[pairCount][2];
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[pairCount*2];
    for(int i = 0;i<pairCount;i++){
        final int index = i;
        //final VolatileExample exp = new VolatileExample();
        //writer
        Thread writer = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                VolatileExample exp = exps[index];
                int val = new Random().nextInt(100);
                valuePair[index][0] = val;
                exp.set(val);
            }
        });
        writer.start();
        threads[i*2] = writer;
        //reader
        Thread reader = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                VolatileExample exp = exps[index];
                while(!exp.changed()){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //System.out.println("waitting for change...");
                }
                int val = exp.get();
                valuePair[index][1] = val;
            }

        });
        reader.start();
        threads[i*2+1] = reader;
    }
    for(Thread t : threads){
        t.join();
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<pairCount;i++){
        int write = valuePair[i][0];
        int read =  valuePair[i][1];
        System.out.println(write+"," + read);
        Assert.assertEquals(write,read);
    }
 }
}
public class VolatileExample {

  private int x;
  private boolean changed = false; 

  public void set(int x){
      this.x = x;
      this.changed = true;
      System.out.println("changed...");
  }

  public int get(){
      return x;
  }

  public boolean changed(){
      return changed;
  }
}
```

You see, the reader thread is waiting for the value x in VolatileExample until the flag property been changed. According to Java specification, the non-volatile property,'changed', will be saved in the respective cache of each thread. But why did my program get the expected results?

I started 1000 pairs of reading and write threads, and each read thread did read the values written by the write threads.

Is there anything wrong with me?

Comment: Non-volatile property `changed` _can_ be saved in thread caches according to specification, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: *two java threads can not coordinate through non-volatile fields* depends on exact scenario

Comment: You have undefined behavior because access to shared variables is unsynchronized. It might appear to work sometimes and sometimes not, depending on the platform.

Comment: The sentence should read `two java threads should not coordinate through non-volatile fields`. It's possible it works 9 out of 10 times, but there is no guarantee that it will succeed.

Comment: Re, "...will be saved in the respective cache of each thread..." A cache is not a place where things are "saved." It is an implementation detail of the hardware and software system that allows the threads to share memory. You won't even find the word "cache" in the Java Language Specification (JLS). What you _will_ find are rules about how to use `synchronized` and `volatile` and various "concurrency" classes. The JLS makes promises about how the system will behave if you follow the rules, but it does not make any promises about what will happen if you break the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked to says:

> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse
>   the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that
>   the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the
>   value of this.done.

This means whether your code works or not depends on whether the compiler decides to cache your variables (doesn't work) or not (works). It is free to do so if it wants, but it doesn't have to.

So your code may or may not work depending on things that are not under your control.